# I'd like to display the segment according to differnet clocks, but I can't

Tags: vhdl

stick shape is fixed to the left of the segment and dot segment want to be displayed separately according to the clock. But at the same time, it's displayed
this is an example pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPBK5.jpg

++)) i want like this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnlpX.jpg

```
    library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

 entity adventure is
port(clk : in std_logic;
     dot_seg : out std_logic;
     select_seg : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     player_in : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     seg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));

  end adventure;

  architecture behavior of adventure is
    signal dot_clk : std_logic;
    signal player_clk : std_logic;
  begin
    process(clk)                
     variable dot_cnt : integer := 0;
     variable player_cnt : integer := 0;
   begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then        
        if dot_cnt >= 5000000 then  -- dot_seg clk
            dot_cnt := 0;
            dot_clk <= not dot_clk;
        else
            dot_cnt := dot_cnt + 1;
        end if;

        if player_cnt >= 50005 then -- player_seg clk
            player_cnt := 0;
            player_clk <= not player_clk;
        else
            player_cnt := player_cnt + 1;
        end if;

    end process;

process(clk, dot_clk, player_clk)       
begin

    if player_clk = '1' then        -- player 
        case player_in is                       
            when "00" => seg <= "1000110";
            when "01" => seg <= "1000011";
            when "10" => seg <= "0010101";
            when "11" => seg <= "1000110";
        end case;
        select_seg <= "01111111";
    end if;

    if dot_clk = '1' then       -- dot(road) segment
        dot_seg <= '1';                ---- put in seg <= "0000000"; ???
        select_seg <= "01011111";
    else
        dot_seg <='1';                 ---- put in seg <= "0000000"; ???
        select_seg <= "10101111";
    end if;


end process;
 end behavior;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. In fact I can't even find a question. Please explain using a bit more text: 1/ what have got at the moment, 2 what is wrong with that or what you want to see instead.

Comment: Your second process is a bit weird, clk is unused. If you want to create a synchronous process, you have to put clk only in sensitivity list.

Comment: The problem is your dot. You have only one signal for all dots. So If you want to have at least one dot on, you have to desactivate all the digits with an expected off dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that for your second process

```
signal digit_display : std_logic := '0';

process(clk)       
begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then

      digit_display <= not(digit_display);

      if digit_display = '1' then

        dot_seg <= '0';

        if player_clk = '1' then        -- player 
          case player_in is                       
            when "00" => seg <= "1000110";
            when "01" => seg <= "1000011";
            when "10" => seg <= "0010101";
            when "11" => seg <= "1000110";
            select_seg <= "01111111";
          end case;
        end if;

      else

        seg <= "0000000"; -- Full off, I don't know polarity

        if dot_clk = '1' then       -- dot(road) segment
          dot_seg <= '1';
          select_seg <= "01011111";
        else
          dot_seg <='1';
          select_seg <= "10101111";
        end if;

      end if;

    end if;

end process;
```

If clk is too fast to blink digit_display, you can put a counter like that :

```
signal digit_display_count : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

if digit_display_count = 100 then -- Choose an appropriate value
  digit_display       <= not(digit_display);
  digit_display_count <= (others => '0')
else
  digit_display_count <= digit_display_count + 1;
end if;
```